# Ideas for a Todo List App features for a beginner with React/React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Working on a Todo List App just hone my knowledge. Currently I can add/remove todos via an input with a submit button/pressing enter. It DOES push to a redux state with a nested array. Any other ideas for features that I could learn some lessons from before I implement MongoDB and start adding user log in and what not?

Answer (score 0):

You can add more information to each task, like a due date, a priority (low, medium, high), a timestamp of when the task was created, or even a checklist (a list within a list!) for each task.

Comment: Ahhh I like those ideas! I have an ID, index, and title that's about it so far. So I'll definitely work on those thanks!